# Casting values and resulting math

Tags: java, casting, int, short

```
short x, y; 
short z = ((short)x) + ((short)y);
```

So I understand that in Java that a value is considered an integer when it is added. It's just one of the nuances in the language. However, here, I am already casting `short` to the variables `x` and `y` and it still gives me an error saying that

> can't convert from int to short

Comment: As you said, the `+` yields an `int`.

Comment: thats a type promotion in java.http://www.java2s.com/Book/Java/0020__Language-Basics/The_Type_Promotion_Rules.htm

Answer (score 6):

> so I understand that in java that a value is considered an integer when it is added.

Not necessarily. Not if you're adding `long`s, for instance.

> However, here, I am already casting short to the variables x and y and it still gives me an error saying that can't convert from int to short.

That's because you're casting the values before they're added; the *result* of the `+` is still an `int`. (In fact, `(short)x` is a no-op; `x` is *already* a `short`.)

The correct way to write that is:

```
short z = (short)(x + y);
```

The `short`s get promoted to `int`s, added together, and then we cast the result back down to a `short`.

Re your comment:

> (I'm) not sure why first casting the x and the y to short and putting them into parentheses would not result in short + short addition

Because Java *doesn't have* `short + short` addition. The smallest size it does addition on is `int`, because [the first thing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.2) the "additive" operators (`+` and `-`) do is [binary numeric promotion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2):

> 1. If any operand is of a reference type, it is subjected to unboxing conversion (§5.1.8).
> 2. Widening primitive conversion (§5.1.2) is applied to convert either or both operands as specified by the following rules:
>
>    - If either operand is of type `double`, the other is converted to `double`.
>    - Otherwise, if either operand is of type float`, the other is converted to`float`.
>    - Otherwise, if either operand is of type `long`, the other is converted to `long`.
>    - Otherwise, both operands are converted to type `int`.

So `short + short` (or `char + char`, or `byte + byte`) becomes `int + int` yielding `int`. The *only* integer additions Java has are `int + int => int` and `long + long => long`.

Comment: I understand what you are saying but I am still logically not sure why first casting the x and the y to short and putting them into parentheses would not result in short + short addition. Does the casting take place separately for x and y, then java AGAIN converts them back to int?

Comment: @Borla312: *"not sure why first casting the x and the y to short and putting them into parentheses would not result in short + short addition"* Because Java *doesn't have* short + short addition. I've expanded the answer to clarify that.

Comment: thank you for the very thorough, detailed, and clear explanation TJ!

Comment: @Borla312: No worries, hope that helped.